# Any software to wrap & isolate a .Net app to run it on Linux?

Tags: .net, linux

I have a couple apps which were written in .Net and include components with hooks into Windows. As such, they do not run under Linux, even with Wine. Mono is also not a solution this time.

My desire is to run these apps with the minimal overhead. So far, I have them running in a virtual machine (host: Windows 10 with most features removed) but that still seems overkill for such a targeted use case.

Is there any tool available where I could actually wrap a .Net app in a pre-configured virtual machine (to ease deployment) either without requiring a Windows license (unlikely, I know) or at least running a version of Windows stripped of everything but the absolute minimum of features (the ONLY reason to run the virtual machine is for this app, no need for calculator, Skype, Edge, etc.)?

Comment: Maybe try to approach this issue from different direction and think of something like Spice Space or Open Thin Client? That is, if you have any other Windows box around.
Also, winetools could deliver some of Windows core components

Comment: I see [Spice Space](https://sourceforge.net/projects/spice-space/) was last updated 4 years ago, which makes me nervous depending on it. I am trying to avoid setting up extra boxes. For that, I can always run Windows in a VM (my main machine is robust enough) but I am trying to get _away_ from Windows. I might be dreaming here, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a product called [CrossOver](https://www.codeweavers.com/products/) that does exactly this. It seems to be related to Wine but I am not sure how much.

What matters is that I could not get my .Net app to run on Wine but I could get it to run through CrossOver (with some support from them). It has some limitations but it does what I need it to do and I do not need to use Windows to run it (I did not even have to re-compile my app).

It is not free, but it is quite cheap (less than $20).

I am not related to CrossOver but I really like what I see so far.